# Passing Data between Scenes in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults, skscene

I've Googled this for about ten minutes, and everybody else's suggestions aren't working for me. I'm simply trying to pass the score of my game from GameScene to GameOver. I'm not using NSUserDefaults but am open to suggestions for it.

I've created my score variable above the `didMove` method.

```
var meteorScore = 0
```

and transition scenes by

```
let reveal = SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1)
let gameOver = GameOver(size: self.size)
self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: reveal)
```

I'm trying to access it like this

```
var score = GameScene(GameScene.level)
```

in GameOver, but I get a few errors. If there's a way to do this with NSUserDefaults instead of like this i'd be happy to switch my code around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try it the other way around.

create your meteorScore variable in GameOver

```
var meteorScore = 0
```

then when transitioning to that scene pass the variable to the scene

```
let reveal = SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1)
let gameOver = GameOver(size: self.size)
gameOver.meteorScore = whateverScoreVariable
self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: reveal)
```

this should do exactly what you're looking for

Comment: I get an error that says: Type 'GameOver' has no member 'meteorScore'

Comment: did you add the variable var meteorScore = 0 in GameOver?

Comment: @RonMyschuck , Yes

Comment: You're going to have to post your code in an edit on your question. This code works, I just retyped into a project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with UserDefaults. For those who are just starting out with UserDefaults, there are a lot of really good videos to learn from.